# Prevent Windows Server 2019 with static IP from detecting new networks?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2019, ip-address

we've got some Windows Server 2019 VMs running on XCP-NG.  They are configured with static IP addresses.  We have two VM hosts: a primary site and a backup site.  Our network admin has created a VLAN that he can switch between the sites if the primary site goes down, which all the VMs are on.

So theoretically, if the primary host goes down, we can just ask the network admin to switch the VLAN over to the backup site, and then start up the backups of the VMs, which should run without any idea that they are on a different host.

In practice, though, when I start the backup VMs, Windows Server 2019 detects that it's on a new network, and it loses the static IP settings.  "Ethernet 2", etc.

Is there any way to disable the detection of new networks, or else force the static IP to remain regardless of network?  I just want the VM to dumbly keep using the same static IP, without any intelligent detection of networks or anything.

I've looked into disabling the Network Location Awareness service, but apparently that's not a good idea, according to some other answers on ServerFault.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to find a nice, automatic solution for this, we are switching to DHCP for the VM networks, binding the MAC addresses to fixed IPs, and then requiring a staff member to manually input the correct MAC address from documentation when they need to start a backup VM.